# Resolve error "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'"

Tags: qgis, python, geostatistics

I am running geostatistics (kriging) in QGIS using the Smart-Map plugin. When I try to cross-validate, the plot does not appear and I get this error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'.

I am using the long-term release version of QGIS (QGIS 3.22.13), the Python version behind it is 3.9.5, and sci-kit-learn 1.2.2. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error.